# Large images in Crystal Reports 2008 - Memory Full

Tags: image, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I've got a C# application targeting .net 4.  The application includes some Crystal Reports reports which can be printed or previewed.  My code uses:

```
CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportClass
```

There is a report, created with Crystal 2008, which dynamically fetches one or more images from the file system.  I'm running into problems when those images are large.

For example:

- The report is trying to include 4 images (each on their own page)
- The source images (.jpgs) are 3.5 megs each

When I print or preview that report, generally the first 2 images appear, but then no more.  Then if I try again I generally will not see any of the images and often get this message box (when previewing):

> **Crystal Reports Windows Forms Viewer**
>
> Memory full.
>
> Not enough memory for operation.

My application is using about 600 megs at that point.

If I swap out those large images for smaller ones (about half a meg each) I'm able to view the report without any problems.

If I preview the same report, with the big images, from within the Crystal Reports 2008 editor, it works perfectly well.

So is there a limit to how many megs of image data I can put into a report when using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportClass?  Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Are you using .Close and .Dispose on your report objects once you are done with them?

Comment: @Telexx: Yes, I'm calling Close and Dispose.  And I see this "memory full" error on the very first time I do the report, so it's definitely not a problem of lost resources from previous reports.  But thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue with reports containing more than 3 images. Solved by changing a setting in the RPT file.
Open your Crystal template, go into File -> Report Options, and unflag the "**Retain Original Image Color Depth**".
This will show pictures with a reduced quality, but will never make the report fail because of "Memory full". At least, that was my case.